# Can you use a void returning function in an expression

Tags: c++, c

Enclosed is a code snippet that I plan on using in my code

```
void error(const char *text)
{
   printf("Error: %s\n", text);
}

int isvalid(int stuff)
{
   if (stuff < 0)
      return (error("Less than zero"), 0);
   else
      return 1;
}
```

Is this ok or bad coding?

The line `return (error("Less than zero"), 0)` does not report an error in my compiler

(Borland C++ V5.0 runtime)

Comment: Are you writing in C or C++?

Comment: A better question is what do you expect it to mean? And why not use `error(...);return 0;`

Comment: @NickA - Well, one can't omit the braces with two statements, even if they are in a single line. Not a *good* reason at all. But still *a* reason.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have to ask it is not good. :-)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, but I would argue that the braces should never be omitted anyway, except *maybe& for only `if` statements on a single line `if(x < 10) x++;` for example

Comment: I am using this code in C but I am not aware if this will break C++.

Comment: @CnCPPcoder - If this isn't a template, it will work just fine in C++ too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you did is syntactically and semantically valid, since the comma operator evaluates each sub-expression and discards all the results but the last<sup>1</sup>.

But it's so un-idiomatic it hurts. Just write two statements. The only awards you'll be winning with this are for code obfuscation.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - You tagged C++, so of course there's a caveat. Operators (including the comma) can be overloaded. And if this was a template, couldn't say if this is well-formed until the template is instantiated. You'd have to jump through some hoops to fix it.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I realise that it could be deemed code obfuscation but you understood the intent. Trying to reduce brace usage can as dangerous as overusing the comma operator. Learning lesson for me here.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid C (and probably C++) because it uses the *comma operator*.

```
error("Less than zero"), 0
```

first evaluates the `error` expression, throws away any result that that might have (it hasn't), and then evaluates the `0`, which then is `return`ed by your function.